# How to read a data from the audio jack port of a cell phone with phonegap

Tags: jquery

I want to make an application with phonegap or android, that reads an entry data through the audio jack port of a cell phone. They could guide me on how to read the data through the port jack. Thank you.

Comment: With jquery?  The dom manipulation library?

Comment: yes, I am doing whith jquery and phonegap